# Why does my umbraco instance not have the buttons named correctly?

Tags: umbraco

My local copy of Umbraco has the save button showing up as [buttons_saveAndPublish] and a lot of the other links in Umbraco have the same issue. I checked my console and I don't have any JavaScript issues showing.

[image: Umbraco Screenshot]

Comment: Could you check if the umbraco language files are present? They should be in `/umbraco/config/lang`

Comment: Mark, yes I have en.xml and en_us.xml and the files appear to have XML, keys & aliases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it looks like it broke when I changed my target framework from 4.5 to 4.6 to fix a TLS related API call issue

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="51200" fcnMode="Single" />
```

Once I changed the 4.6 to 4.5 this issue went away